# joining two tables and getting aggregate data

Tags: sql

how do i write a query that returns aggregate sales data for California in the past x months.

```
 -----------------------        -----------------------
|         order         |      |       customer        |
|-----------------------|      |-----------------------|
| orderId       int     |      | customerId     int    |
| customerId    int     |      | state         varchar |
| deposit       decimal |       -----------------------
| orderDate     date    |   
 ----------------------- 


                  ----------------------- 
                 |      orderItem        |
                 |-----------------------|
                 | orderId      int      |
                 | itemId       int      |
                 | qty          int      |
                 | lineTotal    decimal  |
                 | itemPrice    decimal  |
                  -----------------------
```

Comment: What have you tried?  For what database?  Seldom do I see a brand new account post using formatting...

Comment: What are you looking to aggregate?  Total sales value, number of orders by customer, total deposit, total number of items sold?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're looking for the total of `qty` for each `orderItem` on all `order`s with `customer`s located in `'CA'` (if you want to sum other fields, it shouldn't be too tough to modify the query):

```
SELECT
    SUM(oi.qty) as TotalQuantitySold
FROM
    orderItem oi
    INNER JOIN order o
        ON oi.orderId = o.orderId
    INNER JOIN customer c
        ON o.customerId = c.customerId
WHERE
    c.state = 'CA'
    AND DATEDIFF(month, o.orderDate, <some fixed date>)
```

`DATEDIFF` is from T-SQL, and calculating that date difference may depend on your platform

Comment: Teach to fish, don't give out fish.

Comment: There's something to be said for learning from a specific answer as well.  He's a brand new user so I cut him some slack.